# PHP: Skip/Remove lines starting with ###

Tags: php, file

I need to be able to skip the first 20 lines from a file that start with a ###. (Actually 18 lines start with ### and two start with ;).

Everything I've tried fails to skip the same two lines – I have no clue why.

Here's what I've tried (this is only the relevant part of my code):

```
elseif($sourceformat == "Babylon") {

    $line = fgets($source_file);
    if($line[0] === '#') {
        continue;
    }
    if(strpos(trim($line), '#') === 0) {
        continue;
    }
    if(substr($line, 0, 1) == "#") {
        continue;
    }

    $source = trim(fgets($source_file));

    if(empty($source)) {
        continue;
    }

    $target = trim(fgets($source_file));
}
// then I proceed to writing the extracted terms into a new file that has a different format.
```

I've tried the three approaches above separately and all together (`$line[0] === '#'` and `strpos(trim($line), '#')` and `substr($line, 0, 1) == '#')` – but the same line is always skipped (undetected). Here's what the whole header section looks like (this is the header of a Babylon glossary file (.gls – but plain text).

```
### Glossary title:Cheeseus Muzik
### Author:Cheeseus
### Description:English - Bulgarian and Bulgarian - English glossary of musical terms
### Source language:Bulgarian
### Source alphabet:Cyrillic
### Target language:Bulgarian
### Target alphabet:Cyrillic
### Icon:
### Browsing enabled?Yes
### Type of glossary:00000000
### Case sensitive words?0
; DO NOT EDIT THE NEXT **SIX** LINES  - Babylon-Builder generated text !!!!!!
### Glossary id:0265922f91878d6e846e9c869d8a89447c6e719e8585886b8692955f91887a9b8474859a85616a279a929ca07f6881507056895d6881304b5142515f42ba6c992e2b23828188719469656840908429504d595b486965418931312d5b47ad7843525650833a233a47514270695543449f31373b7179484e435a8c428827
### Confirmation string:8A148GOK
### File build number:0121DA07
### Build:80"0)2"0
### Glossary settings:00000000
### Gls type:00000001
; DO NOT EDIT THE PREVIOUS **SIX** LINES  - Babylon-Builder generated text !!!!!!

### Glossary section:

a piacere
а пиачере, по желание

a tempo
а темпо, завръщане към основното темпо след отклонение

ad libitum
ат либитум, свободно, по желание

adagio
адажио (бавно)

allargando
аларгандо, забавяне

allegretto
алегрето, весело, бързичко

allegro
алегро, бързо, весело

allentando
алентандо, със забавяне

... (this is the actual glossary – source term on one line, target term on the next, followed by an empty line, then again source term, target term, new line. I only want these lines, while discarding (omitting, removing) the glossary header lines above. The code I have successfully removes all lines starting with # but this one below (the glossary ID), and it also removes the two lines starting with a semi-colon.
```

This is the line I can't seem to get rid of:

```
### Glossary id:0265922f91878d6e846e9c869d8a89447c6e719e8585886b8692955f91887a9b8474859a85616a279a929ca07f6881507056895d6881304b5142515f42ba6c992e2b23828188719469656840908429504d595b486965418931312d5b47ad7843525650833a233a47514270695543449f31373b7179484e435a8c428827
```

I suspect this is because this line is quite long (or could it be because the preceding line starts with a semi-colon?). I've tried specifying the max. byte-length for each line being read in `fgets`:

```
$line = fgets($source_file, 8192);
```

But this didn't work either. Hope you can help.

The whole code is too long to put here and it is already working just fine – except for getting rid of this single line.

**SOLUTION (based on @Mehdi Bounya's answer)**

It seems I wasn't performing the checks I already had in place in the correct place. Here's the code that does exactly what I need:

```
elseif($sourceformat == "Babylon") {

    if($targetformat == "Wordfast") {
        $converted_source_target_delimiter = "\t";
        $converted_term_delimiter = "\r\n";
    }

    $source = trim(fgets($source_file));

    if(empty($source)) {
        continue;
    }
    if($source[0] === '#') {
        continue;
    }
    if($source[0] === ';') {
        continue;
    }

    $target = trim(fgets($source_file));
}
$exported_entry = $source.$converted_source_target_delimiter.$target.$converted_term_delimiter;
```

*Thank you to everyone who offered help!*

Comment: You could use a regex, https://regex101.com/r/LILbTu/1/. For `#` or `;` use a character class `[;#]`.

Comment: I tried this, not sure if correct, I don't really know how to write regex, got this from another post: `if(preg_match_all("/^#(.*)$/m", $line)) { continue; }` – but the problem persists, all lines starting with # and ; are removed (skipped) except for the line `### Glossary id:....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the file with `fopen` and loop through the lines, then simply check if the line starts with the character you want.

This function takes two parameters, `$file` is the file path and `$startWith` is an array of characters to skip:

```
function skipLines($file, $startWith = NULL){
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            if(in_array($buffer[0], $startWith)){
                // Your code if line starts with $startWith
            } else {
                // Your code if line does not start with $startWith
                echo $buffer;
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

skipLines("sample.txt", ['#']); // Result 1


skipLines("sample.txt", [';']); // Result 2


skipLines("sample.txt", ['#', ';']); // Result 3
```

Result 1:

```
; DO NOT EDIT THE NEXT **SIX** LINES  - Babylon-Builder generated text !!!!!!
; DO NOT EDIT THE PREVIOUS **SIX** LINES  - Babylon-Builder generated text !!!!!!
```

Result 2:

```
### Glossary title:Cheeseus Muzik
### Author:Cheeseus
### Description:English - Bulgarian and Bulgarian - English glossary of musical terms
### Source language:Bulgarian
### Source alphabet:Cyrillic
### Target language:Bulgarian
### Target alphabet:Cyrillic
### Icon:
### Browsing enabled?Yes
### Type of glossary:00000000
### Case sensitive words?0
### Glossary id:0265922f91878d6e846e9c869d8a89447c6e719e8585886b8692955f91887a9b8474859a85616a279a929ca07f6881507056895d6881304b5142515f42ba6c992e2b23828188719469656840908429504d595b486965418931312d5b47ad7843525650833a233a47514270695543449f31373b7179484e435a8c428827
### Confirmation string:8A148GOK
### File build number:0121DA07
### Build:80"0)2"0
### Glossary settings:00000000
### Gls type:00000001

### Glossary section:
```

Result 3:

```
// Nothing...
```

Comment: I actually want to skip the lines starting with a semi-colon, too. But with the code I already have, they are somehow skipped without being explicitly indicated.

Anyway, the code you suggest is not different from what I already have:
    if($line[0] === '#') {
        continue;
    }
And it's not working – the same two lines are still there.

Comment: I have made a separate file, removing all other code (pertaining to different conversion formats) so that i can test your suggestion. It does work but I also want to get rid of the lines starting with a semi-colon. I suppose I can just add one more `if($buffer[0] === ';')`.

Comment: @cheeseus Check the updated answer for a better way to check for multiple characters.

Comment: Thank you @Mehdi Bounya!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Mehdi Bounya's answer above, this code will store all non "#" lines into an array. The comparing is also done using substr as an alternative.

```
$correct_lines = [];

$handle = fopen("logs.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if (substr($line, 0, 1) !== "#") {
            array_push($correct_lines, $line);
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "Error opening the file";
}

foreach ($correct_lines as $line) {
    echo $line;

    // ; DO NOT EDIT THE NEXT **SIX** LINES  - Babylon-Builder generated text !!!!!!
    // ; DO NOT EDIT THE PREVIOUS **SIX** LINES  - Babylon-Builder generated text !!!!!!
}
```

Comment: The lines starting with a semi-colon are not wanted either. The lines starting with # and those starting with ; are all part of the glossary header. I want to remove all of them, and proceed reading the actual glossary, which I then convert into a different format. I will edit my original question to add a larger part of the file and my code.